# hive left join with 2 factor, one of them is Not equal, AND I want the list in A while not in B

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I want to achieve this effect in hive :

```
select a.* from entry_data_fxj_cl a left join exit_data b 
    on trim(a.ecardid) = trim(b.ecardid) and abs(a.entrytime-b.entrytime)>60000
    where trim(b.ecardid) IS NULL
```

b.entrytime should match the closest time  to A.entrytime

How to express unequal ?

How to express closest ?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to write this as:

```
select edf.*
from entry_data_fxj_cl edf
where not exists (select 1
                  from exit_data ed
                  where trim(ed.ecardid) = trim(edf.ecardid) and
                        ed.entrytime > edf.entrytime - 60000 and
                        ed.entrytime < edf.entrytime + 60000
                 );
```

Does this work for you in Hive?

Comment: I tried:SQL Error:
An exception was caught.
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: Line 6:24 Unsupported SubQuery Expression '60000': SubQuery expression refers to both Parent and SubQuery expressions and is not a valid join condition.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to move non-equality join condition to the `WHERE` and add `OR IS NULL` to allow left join.
Please see comments in the SQL code:

```
select * 
from
(--move non-equality condition to the where + OR is null to allow left join
select a.*, b.ecardid as b_ecardid 
  from entry_data_fxj_cl a left join exit_data b 
    on trim(a.ecardid) = trim(b.ecardid)
where abs(a.entrytime-b.entrytime)>60000 or b.ecardid is NULL --allow left join
)s 
where b_ecardid IS NULL --filter only rows for which b.ecardid is not found
```

Comment: Thanks ,but ecarid is not unique, and  i want B.entrytime is the most recent to A.entrytime

Comment: @vipqiaojin It is not clear. Please provide example and desired output